# Change to a cyclic unlimited while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have a photo gallery that has a previous and a Next link. When it gets to the last image it stops there. I want it to start over at the first picture. The function is a for loop and I think it should be a while loop and some things changed to make it an infinite loop. I just don't know how to convert this function. Still not that strong in PHP. Any help is appreciated.

```
$query  = "SELECT pho_id FROM album_photos WHERE alb_id='$alb_id' ORDER by srt_id ASC";
    $ret    = mysql_query($query);
    $num    = mysql_numrows($ret);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++)
    {
        $row = trim(mysql_result($ret, $i));
        if ($row == $pho_id)
        {
                        $cur = $i;
            $forw = @trim(mysql_result($ret, ($i+1))) or $forw = NULL;
            $back = @trim(mysql_result($ret, ($i-1))) or $back = NULL;
        }

    }
$query = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE pho_id='$back'";
        $rets  = mysql_query($query);
        $back_good = mysql_numrows($rets);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM photos WHERE pho_id='$forw'";
        $rets  = mysql_query($query);
        $forw_good = mysql_numrows($rets);

    $back = "photo-$per_id-$back-$alb_id.html";
    $forw = "photo-$per_id-$forw-$alb_id.html";

    if (strstr($back, 'pho_id=&') || $back_good == 0) { $back = NULL; }
    if (strstr($forw, 'pho_id=&') || $forw_good == 0) { $forw = NULL; }
    $ret = array();

    $ret['back'] = $back;
    $ret['next'] = $forw;
    $cur++;
    $ret['viewing']   = "Photo $cur of ".($num);

    if($ret['back'] == NULL){
    $ret['back'] = "";
    $spacer = str_repeat('&nbsp;',12);
    }
    if($ret['next'] == NULL){
    $ret['next'] = "";
    $spacer = str_repeat('&nbsp;',12);
    }
```

Comment: It has to stop at some point, you surely do *not* want a true infinite loop. What's the stopping condition? Maybe you can demonstrate with some desired example output?

Comment: You should probably sit down and rethink what it is you want to be doing, because using a loop (finite or not) does not make any sense whatsoever here.

Comment: Ok maybe i don't need a infinite loop, but I guess I'm used to desktop applications that do loop continuously depending on what you're doing. anyway, I explained above that I want my photo gallery to be a continuous cycle like Facebook. When you get to the last picture, when you hit the next button you get the first photo in that album. the way it is now, it will stop at the last photo in the album instead of starting over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest modifying your loop's if content like this.

```
$cur = $i;

//compute the indexes of the next and previous elements
//the next item is the first if we are at the end.
$forward_index = $i == $num - 1 ? 0 : $i + 1; 
//the previous one is the last if we are at the beginning.
$backward_index = $i === 0 ? $num - 1 : $i - 1;

//fetch the elements
$forw = @trim(mysql_result($ret, $forward_index));
$back = @trim(mysql_result($ret, $backward_index));

//exit the for loop
break;
```

It is true you could turn the for loop into a while loop. However, there is no absolute need for this. I added a break statement in order to quit as soon as you locate the element you want to load.

**Edit:** fixed the code as per the OP comment. Silly mistake

Comment: thanks but that's not quite workinbg.  I think the rest of the function might be causing an issue because of how it's designed. Even still, it's not doing a cycle with the images.

Comment: Actually this work sorta, I had to remove some of the bottom code affecting it, that causing it not to show the Next or Previous. However when cyclying through, some of the pho_id arent showing up casuing a 404. It did go to the first image after the last image but the 2nd image after that wasn't there and the pho_id was not pulled. Hmmm, did we miss something?

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Your example works but it had an error in it. The forward_index should've been
$forward_index = $i == $num - 1 ? 0 : $i + 1;  

With the +, it works as expected now going either directions as in my original post. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I'll update the solution to avoid confusing other readers. Sorry for that!